# No Join Predicate Warning - Why Does this query never complete/timeout?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Here is my query that I get a "No Join Predicate" warning:

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d , Company c1 
WHERE  d.CustomerID = c1.CompanyID AND c1.CompanyNumber in 
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('56257100', ','))
OR  
EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('American', ',')) as s     
WHERE d.CustomerID = c1.CompanyID AND c1.CompanyName like '%' + s.items + '%' )
```

Essentially I had two queries, and I want to join them with an OR (get the results from both). I believe it's trying to join the two queries as a Cartesian product, which isn't what I want.

If I separate it as 2 queries and `UNION` the results, it is fast. This however makes me re-structure my dynamic SQL quite a bit. I'd like to keep it formatted where I can have an `OR` there, or an `AND` if need be.

Comment: OR is often much slower than union. It is a better practice to start with Union.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are incorrect. They should be as follows so that it knows d is the same across the OR

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d , Company c1 
WHERE  d.CustomerID = c1.CompanyID AND 
 (
  c1.CompanyNumber in (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split]   ('56257100', ','))
  OR  
  EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('American', ',')) as s     
         WHERE d.CustomerID = c1.CompanyID AND c1.CompanyName like '%' + s.items + '%' ) 
 )
```